# Mysql - Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when try to get lock; try restarting transaction, but the query is not in a transaction

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am receiving this Serialization failure: 1213 deadlock found error quite frequently on a system that I developed and manage.

It occurs on a table that is quite large and busy. It has around 10m rows and probably gets upwards of 40 queries/second at peak, from five servers.

The code does not use transactions. There are no LOCKs on this table. The table is InnoDB and has an auto increment primary key.

The error occurs during the following query:

```
UPDATE `Messages` SET Status='(new status)' WHERE `MessageID`='(ID)'
```

The query is prepared and then executed with PHP and PDO. 99% of the time it works just fine.

What might be causing this and how do I approach debugging it?

I am using PHP 7.0.22 and MySQL Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.20. MySQL is running on a separate server from PHP and is replicated so that `SELECT` queries run on one of the slaves. With a couple of exceptions, it should only be `INSERT`s and `UPDATE`s running on the master DB server.

Thanks!

EDIT: Results of `SHOW ENGINE InnoDB STATUS` :

```
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
2018-01-06 10:36:37 0x7fe606788700
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 492758175, ACTIVE 0 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 3 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 3 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 2871743, OS thread handle 140625951213312, query id 167981859 sg-msg-02.company.local 10.32.80.3 myapp System lock
UPDATE Messages SET ThreadID=9 WHERE Status IS NULL AND ScheduleDate<now() AND ThreadID=0 ORDER BY FairQueuePos, ScheduleDate  LIMIT 50
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 63 page no 438651 n bits 184 index PRIMARY of table `Messaging`.`Messages` trx id 492758175 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 115 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 14; compact format; info bits 0
0: len 8; hex 800000000d3444e8; asc      4D ;;
1: len 6; hex 00001d5ee49e; asc    ^  ;;
2: len 7; hex 7f0000033e0110; asc     >  ;;
3: len 8; hex 800000000000048c; asc         ;;
4: len 12; hex 343437393532323333343436; asc 447952233446;;
5: len 4; hex 5a50a6b5; asc ZP  ;;
6: len 4; hex 5a50a6b4; asc ZP  ;;
7: len 4; hex 5a50a6b5; asc ZP  ;;
8: len 4; hex 5a50a6b4; asc ZP  ;;
9: len 4; hex 80000008; asc     ;;
10: len 1; hex 02; asc  ;;
11: len 30; hex 30313963613639662d393262662d346637372d623465632d353161363165; asc 019ca69f-92bf-4f77-b4ec-51a61e; (total 36 bytes);
12: len 2; hex 8021; asc  !;;
13: len 4; hex 80000005; asc     ;;

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 492758174, ACTIVE 0 sec updating or deleting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
3 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 2 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 2871805, OS thread handle 140625927767808, query id 167981857 sg-msg-03.company.local 10.32.80.4 myapp updating
UPDATE Messages SET Status='Sent', RemoteMessageID='(redacted)', SentDate=now(), RouteID='8' WHERE MessageID='(redacted)' LIMIT 1
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 63 page no 438651 n bits 184 index PRIMARY of table `Messaging`.`Messages` trx id 492758174 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap
Record lock, heap no 115 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 14; compact format; info bits 0
0: len 8; hex 800000000d3444e8; asc      4D ;;
1: len 6; hex 00001d5ee49e; asc    ^  ;;
2: len 7; hex 7f0000033e0110; asc     >  ;;
3: len 8; hex 800000000000048c; asc         ;;
4: len 12; hex 343437393532323333343436; asc 447952233446;;
5: len 4; hex 5a50a6b5; asc ZP  ;;
6: len 4; hex 5a50a6b4; asc ZP  ;;
7: len 4; hex 5a50a6b5; asc ZP  ;;
8: len 4; hex 5a50a6b4; asc ZP  ;;
9: len 4; hex 80000008; asc     ;;
10: len 1; hex 02; asc  ;;
11: len 30; hex 30313963613639662d393262662d346637372d623465632d353161363165; asc 019ca69f-92bf-4f77-b4ec-51a61e; (total 36 bytes);
12: len 2; hex 8021; asc  !;;
13: len 4; hex 80000005; asc     ;;

*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 63 page no 443436 n bits 672 index StatusThreadSchedule of table `Messaging`.`Messages` trx id 492758174 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 398 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 4; compact format; info bits 0
0: SQL NULL;
1: len 4; hex 5a50a6b4; asc ZP  ;;
2: len 2; hex 8021; asc  !;;
3: len 8; hex 800000000d3444e8; asc      4D ;;

*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (1)
```

EDIT 2: `SHOW CREATE TABLE Messages`

```
CREATE TABLE `Messages` (
`MessageID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`UserID` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`DestinationAddress` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`LastUpdate` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`CreationDate` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
`SentDate` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
`ScheduleDate` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
`RouteID` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`Status` enum('Sending','Sent','Delivered','Undeliverable','Failed','Deleted','Deleting','Rejected','Unknown','Expired') DEFAULT NULL,
`RemoteMessageID` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
`ThreadID` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
`FairQueuePos` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
PRIMARY KEY (`MessageID`),
KEY `IX_Relationship44` (`UserID`),
KEY `IX_Relationship67` (`RouteID`),
KEY `RemoteMessageID` (`RemoteMessageID`),
KEY `UserSchedule` (`ScheduleDate`),
KEY `StatusThreadSchedule` (`Status`,`ScheduleDate`,`ThreadID`),
KEY `UserStatus` (`UserID`,`Status`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=221559699 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 MAX_ROWS=4294967295
```

Two notes: Older messages are moved out of the table into an archive table (hence where `AUTO_INCREMENT` is currently at). There is a second table that contains more details about the message (such as the actual contents of the message and other meta data) that is not relevant to this issue.

Also I know there are probably too many keys, I added them many years ago and dare not mess with them :)

Comment: a) check `SHOW ENGINE InnoDB STATUS`. It will tell you more about the deadlock (in a section conveniently named "latest detected deadlock"), e.g. the other offending statement. You may have to wait for it to happen again if it is not listed. Add that information to your question. b) check/make sure your `MessageID`-column is indexed, e.g. if it is the primary key. c) check if you (don't) use autocommit mode, you may not be aware that you are indeed in a transaction.

Comment: a) I have pasted the results in the main post. I am not sure how to usefully interpret them. b) It is the primary key and therefore indexed. c) I do use autocommit mode. Would turning that off resolve the problem? Will doing so create new problems? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for adding the innodb status; judging from that, my guess is that this is due to foreign keys. I made it an answer, as it was too long for a comment, if you do not have foreign keys, it may not be as relevant (although adding some indexes will probably still help). To c) autocommit on is fine, just wanted to make sure it is not off (since then you may have transactions without realizing it). Disabling it may indeed create additional problems (or fix some, that depends on your process/logic, but anyway is not to be done lightly).

Answer (score 1):

If you really do not use a transaction, it looks like an issue with foreign keys. You probably have a self-referencing foreign key from `RemoteMessageID` to `ID` (and some other one).

The first query,

```
UPDATE Messages SET ThreadID=9 
WHERE Status IS NULL AND ScheduleDate<now() AND ThreadID=0 
ORDER BY FairQueuePos, ScheduleDate  LIMIT 50
```

might lock the row that your second query

```
UPDATE Messages SET Status='Sent', 
  RemoteMessageID='(redacted)', SentDate=now(), RouteID='8' 
WHERE MessageID='(redacted)' LIMIT 1
```

references, as well as the updated row itself, and bad timing may result in a deadlock.

Apart from some obvious cases, it's not easy to add a quick fix for deadlocks, especially without seeing and analyzing the complete code/logic. Some general tips can be found [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-deadlocks-handling.html).

It may help to actually use transactions and lock the referenced row with

```
select * from Messages 
where MessageId = '<the Remote MessageID>' or MessageId = '<Id>' for update
```

It will try to lock the row it will use prior to using it, and if it can't, wait until it can, instead of deadlocking (although it may still cause a deadlock). You may need something similar for other foreign keys, although this is the likely suspect.

It may also help to add an index to support your first query (probably something at least including `ThreadID` and/or `Status`, complemented by e.g. `FairQueuePos`) to reduce the number of rows locked by that query, as well as reduce the time to execute that query. I would guess that the second query probably does not even touch rows with `ThreadID=0`, so they should not interfere anymore. But you probably have other tasks and queries that do not seperate that easily.

If nothing helps, just repeating the deadlocked query can be a viable solution too. Since your logic does not require you to use transactions, there should not be a dependency on the current database state, so just repeating it can be fine if it does not happen so often that is slows down your process (too much). Although it seems a bit ugly, you would need to do this for other errors like a lost connection or timeout as well.

This seems to be a batch processing queue system. If you are not too far into your development, and of course depending on a lot of other factors and requirements, you may want to have a look at other existing message queue software, which may make your life a bit easier.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! Most of your comments are already covered unfortunately. There are no foreign keys. The first query shouldn't lock the second query - the first one sets the thread that is processing the message, the second one is run only after a `ThreadID` is set. There is already an index that combines Status, ScheduleDate & ThreadID. I'm around 12 years into development (and production), this seems to be a new problem since moving to PHP 7 / MySQL 5.7.20 / Ubuntu 16. I might try adding Status/ScheduleID/ThreadID to the WHERE clause of the second query to see what happens

Comment: I don't have an index that takes `FairQueuePos` into account. I am always fearful of adding indexes to huge, busy database tables though! I can certainly look for and repeat these deadlocked queries - it seems to only be 2 or 3 out of around 100,000 a day.

Comment: If you already have an index on `ThreadID`, FairQueuePos will not solve it I guess. Can status be null for your 2nd query? Then the threadId probably needs to be before ScheduleDate in your index to prevent overlap. If you do not have a foreign key, without transactions, you should not have 3 lock structures for your query. Are you really sure it's not in a transaction? Unfortunately, debugging it will not get easier going forward. Try to enable the [lock monitor](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-enabling-monitors.html) to get additional info on the locks.

Comment: Note that all InnoDB queries run inside a transaction, because InnoDB is a transactional storage engine.  It's only a question of whether the transaction is explicit (controlled by the user) or implicit (started by issuing a query and committing itself or rolling itself back automatically when the statement succeeds or errors out)... and in this case it doesn't matter.  There's always a transaction for every query, in InnoDB.

Comment: @Solarflare do you see where the user's query is locking the primary key and then trying to lock a record in an index named `StatusThreadSchedule` (which almost certainly includes `ScheduleDate`) ...but that lock is held by the other thread, which happens to be trying to lock the primary key of the row where the user holds the PK lock?  Kind of a classic deadlock.

Comment: @Solarflare - It's certainly not in an explicit transaction. `Status` could be NULL in the second query, so I have moved `ThreadID` as you suggest and we'll see what happens.

Comment: `Status` could be NULL for the 2nd query. I will try setting the `Status` field to non-null when it updates the `ThreadID` in the first query to see if that helps. I can then add a `Status IS NOT NULL` clause in the second query

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot You are right, I actually missed it. I somehow locked into my foreign key idea.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot - theoretically (lol) the 2nd query (that is updating `Status` by primary key) should only be happening on rows that have a non-zero `ThreadID` (the application logic is that the `ThreadID` gets set, then the relevant thread is able to pick up and send the message, setting the `Status` to it's new value once sent (or failed to send). Later, when a message is delivered or has failed after n attempts, another process updates it to `Delivered` or `Failed`. It seems to be this query that is having the deadlock issues.

Comment: @BenHolness Before it gets more confusing: it somehow feels as if `MessageId` isn't your (complete) primary key, but before I shoot again in the dark and totally missing a point, could you verify that? Setting `Status` to not null will probably work. Could you add the `show create table Messages` description?

Comment: `MessageID` is the complete primary key (and is auto-increment). I will add `show create table` in the original post

Comment: @BenHolness Do you maybe have a foreign key pointing from your details table *to* the messages table? (The fk is still nagging at me, maybe without merit...) Otherwise I'm still unsure how you can have 2 locked rows for a query that only updates 1 row by primary key. If that is not what is causing the troubles, setting the status to something not null in the first query, or reordering the index to `(Status,ThreadID,ScheduleDate)` (or adding this as a new index) should remove the overlap (and thus the deadlock) between the two queries.

Comment: No foreign key, I am unsure how this can arise as well. I am scared of table corruption happening when modifying keys on such a large active table, so I will try the non-null status thing next! Thanks so much for your input.

Comment: @Solarflare it's not a foreign key, but similar -- the contention here is between the primary key and a secondary index.  Both transactions want the same row (temporarily, perhaps, in the case of one of them) but they are finding it from opposing directions and colliding when each of them tries for the X lock that the other one holds.

Comment: Adding a single index (Status, FairQueuePos, ScheduleDate) and then order by Status, FairQueuePos, ScheduleDate *might* do the trick.  The change in order by is needed to force that index to be the first one used, and based on the query, this wouldn't change the result.